# Why some pictures appear in Facebook with three coloured bands?

Tags: color

This is not a single occurrence, it's also not limited to a single user. Every now and then I see pictures like this on Facebook:

[image]

And this:

[image]

What went wrong here?

Picture cropped for privacy reasons.

Comment: vtc b/c This question has nothing to do with photography. The colors are from the French flag. Some people intentionally add a flag overlay to their profile photos to show support for their [favorite sports teams](https://www.facebook.com/rio2016profile/) or for [other reasons](https://www.ibtimes.com/facebook-french-flag-why-you-shouldnt-change-your-profile-picture-support-paris-2187416) unrelated to photography.

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown appears to be an example of a simple overlay. A semi-transparent mask is combined with a photo. There are many online "apps" that offer such functionality. One uploads a photo, the site adds the overlay which is displayed on the sender's screen and can then be saved to use as the sender wishes. More advanced apps interact directly with facebook to automate the process of adding an overlay to a user's profile photo.

The masks offered are typically associated with sports teams or "causes" for which the users wish to show their "support."